# Getting an error while importing fibo in IDLE and pycharm

Tags: python, import, module

I'm having a problem with importing fibo in IDLE or other IDE's like pycharm.

```
>>>import fibo

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import fibo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fibo'
```

I tried to solve it by googling but I couldn't solve it. Should I download something?

Comment: did you install the module ?

Comment: yeah...i can import sys or others.....the problem is just with importing fibo

Comment: you have to install the package via `pip` - `pip install fibo` or something like that.

Comment: `sys` is a built-in module, therefore you can import it like you have tried to do. However, `fibo` is not built-in. You will have to install this as @MD.KhairulBasar said above